# log-in/password issues

Tags: linux-mint, password

I'm runnung LM 18.3X "live". Never needed to "log-in", however, after running some upgrades, a different version splash screen showed up and now it's prompting for a log-in/password...which I don't have. How can I get passed this obstruction?

***Rick***

Comment: RE: dsstorefile 1      Thanx for the tip.  Sorry, it didn't help!

Comment: It seems to me you had auto login enabled in what ever login manager you were using. Either the login manager was switched out or its using a different one after the upgrade. When you say its "live" I'm assuming its an older Mint installed from a live cd.

Comment: I have not enabled any log-in designations. Strange; this issue crept up only after, I believe, the 3rd or 4th boot. I'm running LM18.3x 'live", as I said, meaning I'm running 18.3x via a USB flashdrive. I doubt I'd call it an 'older" Mint. Hope this clarifies a bit.